# Pivot aggregation filling columns with value on the same row in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, pivot, transpose

I need to do a pivot aggregation filling columns with answer.

Here below the example, thank u!

`Input`

| id | question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | quest_1 | Good |
| 1 | quest_2 | Bad |
| 2 | quest_1 | Bad |
| 2 | quest_2 | Good |
| 2 | quest_3 | Quite Good |

`Output`

| id | quest_1 | quest_2 | quest_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Good | Bad | *NULL* |
| 2 | Bad | Good | Quite Good |

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a pivot

```
 df.groupby('id').pivot('question').agg(first('answer')).show()
```